# How Do I Restore Aspect Ratio In Adobe Camera Raw

Tags: cropping, canon-5d-mark-iii, adobe-camera-raw, aspect-ratio

I have a stack of RAW photos shot using the in-camera crop on the 5d Mk3 at 1:1 aspect ratio.

When I open them in ACR, I am unable to open out the crop to the native (3:2) aspect ratio. The image previews in-camera and in Finder show these images in their 3:2 entirety.

How do I get these photos back to 3:2?

Comment: Have you tried opening them in Canon's *Digital Photo Professional*?

Comment: I've never even installed the Canon software, but thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a go. What I'm confused by is that the data is still there, so why isn't the crop data editable in ACR?  Surely that's the point of RAW; that data remains editable.

Comment: @Pedr The data is there don't worry. But Adobe applies the cropping you set in camera as default.

Comment: Adobe products ignore most of the *maker note* section of the EXIF info. I suspect that is where your problem lies. When you first open your files in *DPP* they will display in the 1:1 crop, but open the *trimming/angle* tool (Alt+C) and you should be able to change it.

Comment: @MichaelClark Opened in DPP, cleared crop info so that it shows original 3:2 and saved as a new file. However ACR still opens it with 1:1 crop applied.

Comment: can you maybe provide a file for us to experiment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the only solution appears to be:

1. Install [Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) (Free)
2. Open Terminal and navigate to the directory containing the image(s):
3. For a single image called `BD3A6291.CR2` with dimensions of 5760 x 3840 execute:

   exiftool BD3A6291.CR2 -AspectFrame="0 0 0 0" -DefaultCropOrigin="" -DefaultCropSize="" -CroppedImageWidth="5760" -CroppedImageHeight="3840"

Comment: Nice!  It's been a while - want to mark this as accepted?